# db.Database.SqlQuery raw data returns stored procedure name and parameters

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I have a stored procedure which returns 1 row and 1 column containing a string.

I am using the SqlQuery method from db.Database to try and return this method as a string. However when I checked the return value it returns the name of the stored procedure and the parameters I am trying to pass.

```
var val = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(string.Format("{0} @QuestionnaireID", model.ObjectiveB.StoredProcedure.SpName),
    new SqlParameter("QuestionnaireID", model.ProjectId));
```

This is what is returned

[image]

I've also tried using

```
.FirstOfDefault()
```

and

```
.ToList()
```

But still none return the value I want, onlt the name of the stored procedure and it's parameter. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is something like this:

```
var response = Db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC procName @p1={0}, @p2={1}, @p3={2}", v1, v2, v3);

var strResponse = resp.First();
```

Make sure to check the response object for errors first.

Comment: Are you sure this is works in MySQL? I thought you need yo say call procName()?